# Can I transfer the funds from an account with just the account number and password?

Tags: accounts, nodes

I have lost all the files from an Ethereum node where I had an account with some ether in it (I know I should have backed it up). Given than I know the account number and the password, can I transfer the ether into another node?

Comment: Is your private key in hex format or is it encrypted? The encrypted one is a json having address, crypto, id and version keys.

Comment: I put private key, but I meant password, so I've changed the title and question.

Answer (score 7):

I'm sorry but the password is just used to encrypt your private key, **without the private key itself, the network cannot "recognize" you as the owner of the account** and you cannot recover your funds.

You can try to use a disk recovery tool to attempt to recover the keystore file that was in your node_datadir/keystore.

The path on Linux should be:

```
/home/<username>/.ethereum/keystore
```

on OSX:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Ethereum/keystore
```

on Windows:

```
%APPDATA%/Ethereum/keystore
```

The keystore file should look something like this:

```
UTC--2016-01-26T10-05-36.776189549Z--a9f290b5f83744a00014864b7de1c4b8cdf45eb1

UTC--date--address
```

You can try to run the disk recovery tool on that specific dir and make it look for all the files that start with `UTC--`.

Answer (score 6):

**No**, unfortunately.  Basically, **to transfer ether, a private key is needed.**

A private key cannot be obtained from an address ("account number").
Note that going the other direction, an unencrypted private key can always produce the address.

Thus, **the private key is what's essential for backup (and the password to it, if the private key is stored in an encrypted form)**.

That's what the keystore files are, and trying to recover or find them, as other answers suggest, is the only hope at progress.

Answer (score 5):

You need your private key and password (if the private key is encrypted) in order to access your account. If the wallet was a presale wallet or generated somewhere that created a .json file, that .json file also holds your private key.

The presale .json file was called:

```
ethereum_wallet_backup.json
```

The file paths for Windows / Mac / Linux are as follows:

```
Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum/keystore
Linux: ~/.ethereum/keystore
Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum/keystore
```

Do a full and thorough search of your computer, email, and cloud services you use (ie: Dropbox).

How you "lost" the files will impact what steps you can take to recover them. If you dropped your computer in a lake, you probably want to start by getting a wetsuit and going for a quick dive. If they were accidentally deleted (and then you emptied your trash/recycle bin) and it *just* happened, it may be possible to recover them using a data recovery software. If they were overwritten, and it happened very recently. It *may* be possible to recover them using a data recovery software. The sooner you do this the better as the likelihood of the deleted files being overwritten with new data goes up the longer you wait.